# Unable to get group (cumulative response time) for the async events using Karate and Gatling framework

Tags: asynchronous, performance-testing, karate

We have an async event architecture (when we call a REST end point, we get sync response followed by an async event through JMS queue) to load test. We tried using Karate- Gatling framework for this.

I did use grouping from Gatling but not able to get the cumulative response time (for both sync and async response) which is always coming as 0.

```
val playersTestSample = scenario("Sample").group("Sample") {
        exec(
          karateFeature("classpath:FeatureFiles/SamplePerfTest.feature")
        )
    }
```

Report: has all zero's in the response time

[image]

Any ideas or suggestions to load test the async response and get cumulative response time in the Gatling reports for both sync and async responses?

Comment: this is a complex topic, and it is unlikely you can get help without sharing code examples. refer this example where grouping works: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/1467

Comment: by the way if you are having Java code and async, that is a completely different discussion, refer: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-gatling#custom - also refer this example: https://twitter.com/getkarate/status/1417023536082812935

Comment: Thanks Peter, yes we are using java code for the async event capturing. So the last comment is somewhat useful to calculate the async event time however I am still unable to get cumulative of both Sync and async time means I should be able to capture the time when I hit the end point until I receive the async event. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: sorry I can't help more than this especially without being able to see your code. suggest you do some more digging and contribute an answer here and perhaps some example code that will help others